# How to use Encoding.GetString with large amounts of data? (throws OutOfMemoryException)

Tags: c#, encoding, out-of-memory

I am reading binary data from db and converting it into text by using code.

```
       public String BinaryToText(byte[] data)
       {
         System.Text.Encoding encEncoder = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;

         return encEncoder.GetString(data);
       }
```

The above procedure is correctly working but when binary file >= 85mb is converted , OutOfMemoryException
is shown.How to convert large binary data into string without error.

Comment: How you read data from file?

Comment: no i am reading data from sqlserver

Comment: You seem to think ASCII is enough for "BinaryToText"... this is wrong, the encoding of the binary can be in any encoding.

Comment: @Esailija well, it *might* be right; it depends a lot on context. But yes: it is *unlikely* to be right. Normally I would expect UTF-8 or UTF-16 (BE or LE). But it could be any encoding. Or none.

Comment: @MarcGravell It's always in some encoding, there is no such thing as no encoding. But there is no harm in using UTF-8 or an OS code page since they are ASCII supersets... This is probably why the confusion of no encoding exists... because so many encodings encode ASCII characters exactly the same you can have major encoding screw ups all over the place and never notice it because nobody ever used characters outside ASCII or you will notice it when ASCII incompatible encoding is introduced to the screw up mix.

Comment: @Esailija there is plenty such thing as "no encoding"; simply: the data isn't text. Unrelated, but I happen to do some OSS support on a binary serializer. Do you know what the most commonly repeated question is? It is when somebody needs a string and tries to convert non-text binary to a string via the method shown above or similar. Obviously the answer here is "use base-64", but: it would genuinely not amaze me if that is the case here too, and the *data* is a png / pdf / zip / mp4 or something. I see people doing that *virtually every week*.

Comment: @MarcGravell if the data isn't representing plain text, it isn't in *character* encoding but it is still in some encoding. Could be jpg, mp3, pdf, or some ad hoc custom binary format, but it's still in some kind of encoding. Closest thing that matches "no encoding" in text case is ISO-8859-1 (bytes directly cast to char == decode as ISO-8859-1)

Comment: @Esailija meh; that starts getting into overloaded definitions of "encoding"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't normally expect 85MB too be a problem unless you are low on memory etc. Even x86 can usually handle that without pausing for breath.

For large amounts of data, the simplest answer is always "don't hold it all in memory at once". ADO.NET has a forwards-only API on data-reader that allows successive calls to fetch different parts of a large BLOB:

```
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
{  //                                    ^^ forwards-only mode ^^
  long offset = 0;
  int read;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[8096];
  while ((read = reader.GetBytes(colIndex, offset, buffer, 0, buffer.Length))>0)
  {
     ProcessBytes(buffer, 0, read);
     offset += read;
  }
}
```

where `ProcessBytes(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)` processes `count` bytes from `buffer`, starting at `offset`. In the case of ASCII, you can probably get away without using an encoding *at all*; for other encodings, you can use the `Encoding.GetDecoder()` API to decode a stream of data, although it is a bit messy. These two things together will allow you to handle an arbitrarily large (multi-terabyte if necessary)  data-source without having it all in memory at once.

The next question, then, is: what are you going to *do* with this data?

If you *do* need it all in memory at once, you have **no choice** but to hold it. You *might* be able to do something with an iterator block, to return *fragments* of the string in turn.